# CDF Graph looks weird

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, piecewise-pdf

I have this piecewise pdf function:

[image]

with the CDF:

[image]

When I graph the CDF above, I get this graph which looks weird for a CDF and I dunno how to explain what is happening. It looks more like an inverse CDF graph. I am new to this stuff but I need to get it right for my research work.

[image]

EDIT: I am new to PDFs and CDFs so sorry for not being able to be specific. I know that the CDF graph above meets the requirements of a CDF. But comparing it to other CDFs like for the normal distribution among others, this looks like it's upside down. I just wanna be sure that it is right or I am doing something wrong and perhaps get some intuition as to why it is shaped that way. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: You need to give more detail

Comment: @AdamO It looks like the CDF graph is upside down. I dunno if you get me.

Comment: This function $F$ is an increasing continuous function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$, hence a CDF.

Comment: Plot the density to get another handle on the distribution. It's evident from that plot that the area under the distribution is 1.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what might look "weird" about this plot?  Note, please, that $f$ is decidedly *not* a pdf: the area beneath it is infinite.  Evidently, the formula for $f$ is intended to apply only to arguments $x$ between $0$ and $1.$  You will find it helpful, then, to construct an accurate graph of $F$ for a range of values of $x$ that extends a little beyond $0$ and $1$ in both directions.  Please do that and then tell us what looks "weird" about it.

Comment: @whuber the formula is intended for x values between 0 and 1.  I do not understand what you mean by f is not a pdf. Does it not meet the requirements of a pdf?

Comment: I think that @whuber is hinting that the pdf -- just like the cdf -- is only to be considered within the range [0,1]. Consider the meaning of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ dx$,

Comment: (1) Your formulas for $f$ *explicitly* cover all real values of $x:$ there is no restriction to $0\le x \le 1.$  This is not just a nitpick, because by definition *all* CDFs are defined for *all* real numbers.  It's truly helpful to plot them over a range where they rise from $0$ (or nearly so) to $1$ (or nearly so).  (2) Even allowing that your CDF is focusing on the interval $[0,1],$ by plotting it only in part of that interval you create a false impression.  So, once again: *please plot your CDF over at least the interval $[0,1]$.*